# C++ code to indent XML line

Tags: c++, xml

I am looking for C++ code to indent an xml line. I don't want to link with a library.

I have my stream in one line like this

```
<root><a>value_a</a><b>value_b</b></root>
```

and I want to print it in a multi-line way (with tabs).

```
<root>
   <a>value_a</a>
   <b>value_b</b>
</root>
```

does it ring a bell to anybody?

Comment: I once asked something like this, but unfortunately C++ doesn't not come with something default that you can use, which PHP and C# does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to use a library, you will have to write it yourself. That should not be too hard. You will first have to [tokenize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) the stream into tags and values. This is the hardest part I guess. Then you have to write the tokens to a stream. For every opening tag that follows an opening tag, you increase the indent, and for every closing tag that follows a closing tag you decrease the indent.

Some hints for the tokenizing. I think what I would try is to write a simple XMLToken class like this:

```
class XMLToken {
public:
    enum ElementType { OpenTag, CloseTag, Value };
    std::string content;
    ElementType elementType;
};
```

These members should be encapsulated with appropriate getters and setters, this is just for illustration. Then I would overload the stream extraction operator for this type:

```
std::istream & operator >>(st::istream & stream, XMLToken & token) {
    // if first char is '<', then token is a tag, otherwise a value
    // read until '>' is found for a tag and until '<' is found for a value
    return stream;
}
```

Then you can use an `istream_iterator` for tokenizing the stream:

```
typedef std::istream_iterator< XMLToken > XMLTokenizer;
for ( XMLTokenizer it = XMLTokenizer(some_istream); it != XMLTokenizer; it++ ) {
    // process token
}
```

Hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Use [TinyXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/)

---

There's a `class TiXmlPrinter`  there, that will do this job for you. Also, working with `TiXmlDocument` is pretty easy, fast and clear.

Parsing whole XML document is very easy, too. With `TinyXML` you could manipulate the XML structure like a real tree. There's a really good JavaDoc in the headers of the library.

Comment: I cannot add this library in my system. Is there pure C++ code?

Comment: It is pure C++ code, with headers and cpp files. Otherwise, I don't know any other way, probably you will need to write your own parser or printer for XML.

Comment: @cateof: You should add this kind if information to you question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/xmltutorial.pdf) function xmlSaveFormatFile(const char * filename, xmlDocPtr cur, int format). The first parameter is the name of the file to be written, the second parameter is a pointer to the xmlDoc structure and by setting the third parameter to one the output will be indented.